# PHP: Echo Result Number

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching a number of results from my database using a `mysql_query`. What I need to do is `echo` the result number, along with the result itself.

In other words, if my query fetches 3 results, I would like the first result to have a `1` beside it, and the second result a `2` and so on. **I need the numbers to start at 1, not 0.**

**note:** I do not mean `mysql_num_rows` as that only tells me how many results, not the result number itself.

**Here is my query information:**

```
$primary_img_query = "SELECT imgURL, imgTitle FROM primary_images WHERE primaryId=16";
$primary_img_data = mysql_query($primary_img_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) { 
    echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>";//this is where I want the result number echoed
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a counter:

```
$count = 1;

while(...){
   echo $count++;
}
```

---

In your case:

```
$count = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) { 
   echo $count++;
   echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that will work, but I won't be able to test it until later. I'll let you know if I have any problems.

Answer (score 4):

One other solution I don't see mentioned here is using an ordered list:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);

echo "<ol>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<li><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></li>";
}
echo "</ol>\n";
```

This gives you more "correct" HTML, if you don't particularly care about the result number in your PHP code. (Nothing stops you from using both, either: use an ordered list to output the number, but keep a counter for other things, like `rel` attributes or alternating CSS classes.)

Comment: Alas this will not work as I actually need to use the number in the class of the image. Ie class='image(x)' where x is the result number. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: True. But like I said, nothing stops you from using both, if you need to. Just wanted to throw the idea out there.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) { 
    echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>";//this is where I want the result number echoed
    echo $counter++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) { 
    echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>" . $i;
    $i ++;
}
```

Comment: holy **.. what are the odds ;D

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) {
      echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>" . $i;//this is where I want the result number echoed
      $i++;
}
```

Comment: why repeat? just do `echo $i++`

Answer (score 2):

A little bit brutish, but why not just keep a counter?

```
$primary_img_query = "SELECT imgURL, imgTitle FROM primary_images WHERE primaryId=16";
$primary_img_data = mysql_query($primary_img_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$n=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data)) { 
    $n++;
    echo "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'>" . $n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline counters, for the win.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($primary_img_data))
{ 
    echo ++$i . "<img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/" . $row['imgURL'] . "'><br>";
}
```

This is not materially different than any other answer here, other than it's 1 line shorter and actually leverages the fact that you can use incrementors inline.